# Amazon AWS Server persistent storage for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a new PHP app on Amazon AWS using ElasticBeanstalk. The problem I am facing is whenever the EC2 instance is terminated my data in uploads folder get removed. What can I do to retain the data even if the EC2 instance is terminated or a new instance is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an S3 bucket and store any persistent files in that - as you've discovered EC2 instances to not have any persistent storage of their own.

Comment: thanks @Bulk, how can i use that bucket in php for storing my uploads?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is the way to go to store persistent files as suggested by Bulk. Additionally you can use Azamon CloudFront (CDN) to serve the static content. I have found the following [example](http://blog.ianbeyer.com/2012/01/19/php-direct-upload-s3/) to upload to S3 using PHP. Here is another [PHP class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) to upload files to S3.